I use pre-render in Quarto and want to include the result in the gitlab repo
I have a Quarto website, I want to include an external blog and use a python script to scrape the feed. The script produces a yml-file.
I then host my website in a gitlab repo with a CI.
I use pre-render in my quarto-file to produce my rss_blog.yml file. It works perfectly fine locally, but when I run the pipeline, the file is not updated.
I tried including the script directly in the pipeline, it was then stored as an artifact, but not in the repo. I tried an access token, but I still hat problems with 2FA-authentification.
I then tried to include my python-file as pre-render in the quarto-file, but it only works locally and not in the gitlab
Here are some code-snippets:
python:
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import yaml

import re

import html

from datetime import datetime

....

# URL of the RSS feed

rss_url = 'https:/example.com/feed'# Convert the list of entries to a YAML file
with open(yaml_file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    yaml.dump(entries, file, allow_unicode=True, default_flow_style=False)

_quarto:
project:
  type: website
  output-dir: public
  pre-render: blog.py
lang: de

CI:
image: python:3.9  

pages:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3-pip
    - pip3 install requests beautifulsoup4 pyyaml lxml
    - wget https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/releases/download/v1.3.433/quarto-1.3.433-linux-amd64.deb
    - dpkg -i quarto-1.3.433-linux-amd64.deb
  environment: production
  script:
    - echo "Running pre-render script"
    - python3 blog.py
    - echo "Directory contents after script execution:"
    - ls -la
    - echo "Rendering Quarto site"
    - quarto render
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH

